# iOS Programming: Making an arc4_random not repeat itself using a do while loop

Tags: ios, swift, arc4random

In this code 2nd line goes through the array and output what it receives and its random. But sometimes I get the same thing twice, like it would say "Straub", and then "Straub" and then something else like "Rusher". I've tried to do a "do while loop" but I don't know how to set it up where it doesn't repeat itself. By the way this the swift programming language.

```
let types = ["Alex", "Straub", "Rusher", "Graser"]

let type = types[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))]

println(type)
```

If you have any questions please post them in the comments section

Comment: When you roll a dice there is a chance to get the same number twice in a row...

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @SteveRosenberg that is all the code I have I want the names to display but, I don't want one to repeat. I want all of them to be random but none repeating.

Comment: Oh, are you suffering from repeats simply because random luck will lead to repeats?

Comment: @TheCampingRusher 'All of them to be random but none repeating' is an oxymoron. If you can make predictions about the forthcoming output based on the current output, it's not random.

Comment: What you're looking for is a random shuffle, not a random number. This has been answered many times on SO.

Comment: I would take a copy of your array, and remove the items as they are selected.  Like this:

    let types = ["Alex", "Straub", "Rusher", "Graser"]
    var unselected = types    
    var selection  = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(unselected.count)))
    var type = unselected[selection]
    unselected.removeAtIndex(selection)
    println(type)
    
    selection  = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(unselected.count)))
    type = unselected[selection]
    unselected.removeAtIndex(selection)
    println(type)
What you do once you have exhausted the list is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This avoids a direct repetition:

```
var lastIndex = -1
var index = -1

let types = ["Alex", "Straub", "Rusher", "Graser"]

do {
    index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))
} while index == lastIndex

println(types[index])
lastIndex = index
```

Comment: This code generates one a couple times, it would say Alex Alex Alex Alex Alex then Straub I need it so that it doesnt repeat itself but is still somewhat random